# Accessing "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" of client pc from server in C#

Tags: c#

I have build a code in C# to fetch product key of local system,the problem is to fetch the product key of all system connected under a domain with a connection.

### Connection file

```
ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connectionOptions.Username = WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.domain + "\\" + WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.user_name;
connectionOptions.Password = WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.password;
ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope();
managementScope.Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + ip + @"\root\CIMV2");
managementScope = Connection.SetConnectionScope(ip, connectionOptions);

try
{
    managementScope.Connect();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    continue;
}

Connection wmiConnection = new Connection(WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.user_name,
                                          WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.password,
                                          WMI_Hardware.Properties.Settings.Default.domain,
                                          ip);
```

### Product KEY

```
    RegistryKey localKey;
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
    }
    else
    {
        localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
    }

    var value = (byte[])localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Registration\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}").GetValue("DigitalProductId");

    var digitalProductId = value;

    var isWin8OrUp =
        (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 2)
        ||
        (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6);

    var productKey = isWin8OrUp ? DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(digitalProductId) : DecodeProductKey(digitalProductId);
    localKey.Close();
    return productKey;
}

public static string DecodeProductKey(byte[] digitalProductId)
{
    const int keyStartIndex = 52;
    const int keyEndIndex = keyStartIndex + 15;
    var digits = new[]
    {
    'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
    'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    };
    const int decodeLength = 29;
    const int decodeStringLength = 15;
    var decodedChars = new char[decodeLength];
    var hexPid = new ArrayList();
    for (var i = keyStartIndex; i <= keyEndIndex; i++)
    {
        hexPid.Add(digitalProductId[i]);
    }
    for (var i = decodeLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Every sixth char is a separator.
        if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0)
        {
            decodedChars[i] = '-';
        }
        else
        {
            // Do the actual decoding.
            var digitMapIndex = 0;
            for (var j = decodeStringLength - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                var byteValue = (digitMapIndex << 8) | (byte)hexPid[j];
                hexPid[j] = (byte)(byteValue / 24);
                digitMapIndex = byteValue % 24;
                decodedChars[i] = digits[digitMapIndex];
            }
        }
    }
    return new string(decodedChars);
}

public static string DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(byte[] digitalProductId)
{
    var key = String.Empty;
    const int keyOffset = 52;
    var isWin8 = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] / 6) & 1);
    digitalProductId[66] = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] & 0xf7) | (isWin8 & 2) * 4);

    const string digits = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
    int last = 0;
    for (var i = 24; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var current = 0;
        for (var j = 14; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            current = current * 256;
            current = digitalProductId[j + keyOffset] + current;
            digitalProductId[j + keyOffset] = (byte)(current / 24);
            current = current % 24;
            last = current;
        }
        key = digits[current] + key;
    }

    var keypart1 = key.Substring(1, last);
    var keypart2 = key.Substring(last + 1, key.Length - (last + 1));
    key = keypart1 + "N" + keypart2;

    for (var i = 5; i < key.Length; i += 6)
    {
        key = key.Insert(i, "-");
    }

    return key;
}
```

While running the above code it do not fetch product key  from the assigned IP address which arrives from the domain .It fetch product key of  current system in which the code is running.

Comment: This may require that the Remote Registry Service is running on all applicable workstations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string GetWindowsProductKey() {
  RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "SOMANATHAN", RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey(@ "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

  var isWin8OrUp =
    (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 2) ||
    (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6);

  var productKey = isWin8OrUp ? DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(digitalProductId) : DecodeProductKey(digitalProductId);
  environmentKey.Close();
  return productKey;
}
```

Pass system username in a loop in Registrykey environment.

**Example:** Instead of `somanathan` pass `Ravi` if system name is `Ravi` to fetch the product key of windows that are connected in a domain.

**NOTE:** Also enable RPC service in the system.